# xcode error while running on device

Tags: ios, xcode

Hi am getting an error repeatedly when trying to run my code on device (iPad). An error which says at the end of its huge description 
Command /Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 254

I need to clean,remove derived data, quit and restart xcode every time i switch to run from simulator to device. 
Heres the full error description -

```
CompileC /Users/c5180645/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SalesMap-apwauterdbqwwrfeudcmuixcsupw/Build/Intermediates/SalesMap.build/Debug-iphoneos/SalesMap.build/Objects-normal/armv7/BriefcaseOperationsServiceAgent.o "SalesMaps/Classes/Service Agents/BriefcaseOperationsServiceAgent.m" normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /Users/c5180645/Perforce/SalesMapJan/onDevice/SAPGDBLR_SalesMap_MiOS/dev/src/xcode
    setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
    setenv PATH "/Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -arch armv7 -fmessage-length=0 -std=gnu99 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wmissing-prototypes -Wreturn-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wformat -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wno-empty-body -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wno-undeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DDEBUG=1 -isysroot /Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -Wno-sign-conversion "-DIBOutlet=__attribute__((iboutlet))" "-DIBOutletCollection(ClassName)=__attribute__((iboutletcollection(ClassName)))" "-DIBAction=void)__attribute__((ibaction)" -miphoneos-version-min=4.1 -iquote "/Users/c5180645/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SalesMap-apwauterdbqwwrfeudcmuixcsupw/Build/Intermediates/SalesMap.build/Debug-iphoneos/SalesMap.build/Sales Maps-generated-files.hmap" "-I/Users/c5180645/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SalesMap-apwauterdbqwwrfeudcmuixcsupw/Build/Intermediates/SalesMap.build/Debug-iphoneos/SalesMap.build/Sales Maps-own-target-headers.hmap" "-I/Users/c5180645/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SalesMap-apwauterdbqwwrfeudcmuixcsupw/Build/Intermediates/SalesMap.build/Debug-iphoneos/SalesMap.build/Sales Maps-all-target-headers.hmap" -iquote "/Users/c5180645/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SalesMap-apwauterdbqwwrfeudcmuixcsupw/Build/Intermediates/SalesMap.build/Debug-iphoneos/SalesMap.build/Sales Maps-project-headers.hmap" -I/Users/c5180645/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SalesMap-apwauterdbqwwrfeudcmuixcsupw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/include -ISalesMaps/Libraries -ISalesMaps/Libraries/GSComponent -ISalesMaps/Libraries/VFR -ISalesMaps/Libraries/GSComponent/Classes -ISalesMaps/Libraries/VFR/Classes -ISalesMaps/Libraries/VFR/Resources "-I/Users/c5180645/Perforce/SalesMapJan/onDevice/SAPGDBLR_SalesMap_MiOS/dev/src/xcode/../../target/headers/Debug-iphoneos/**" -I/Users/c5180645/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SalesMap-apwauterdbqwwrfeudcmuixcsupw/Build/Intermediates/SalesMap.build/Debug-iphoneos/SalesMap.build/DerivedSources/armv7 -I/Users/c5180645/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SalesMap-apwauterdbqwwrfeudcmuixcsupw/Build/Intermediates/SalesMap.build/Debug-iphoneos/SalesMap.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/c5180645/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SalesMap-apwauterdbqwwrfeudcmuixcsupw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -include /Users/c5180645/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SalesMap-apwauterdbqwwrfeudcmuixcsupw/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/SalesMap-Prefix-etkfpououlszbidzxbhsxwstcvcl/SalesMap-Prefix.pch -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/c5180645/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SalesMap-apwauterdbqwwrfeudcmuixcsupw/Build/Intermediates/SalesMap.build/Debug-iphoneos/SalesMap.build/Objects-normal/armv7/BriefcaseOperationsServiceAgent.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/c5180645/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SalesMap-apwauterdbqwwrfeudcmuixcsupw/Build/Intermediates/SalesMap.build/Debug-iphoneos/SalesMap.build/Objects-normal/armv7/BriefcaseOperationsServiceAgent.dia -c "/Users/c5180645/Perforce/SalesMapJan/onDevice/SAPGDBLR_SalesMap_MiOS/dev/src/xcode/SalesMaps/Classes/Service Agents/BriefcaseOperationsServiceAgent.m" -o /Users/c5180645/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SalesMap-apwauterdbqwwrfeudcmuixcsupw/Build/Intermediates/SalesMap.build/Debug-iphoneos/SalesMap.build/Objects-normal/armv7/BriefcaseOperationsServiceAgent.o

0  clang             0x0000000101058eb2 main + 17130162
1  clang             0x0000000101059339 main + 17131321
2  libsystem_c.dylib 0x00007fff89fdb92a _sigtramp + 26
3  clang             0x0000000100303825 main + 3148837
4  clang             0x00000001003062c8 main + 3159752
5  clang             0x0000000100305fd1 main + 3158993
6  clang             0x000000010030275f main + 3144543
7  clang             0x00000001002fe0aa main + 3126442
8  clang             0x00000001002f13a9 main + 3073961
9  clang             0x00000001001cf1b7 main + 1885623
10 clang             0x00000001001ca43d main + 1865789
11 clang             0x00000001001ca305 main + 1865477
12 clang             0x00000001001ca1ed main + 1865197
13 clang             0x0000000100197f8c main + 1659788
14 clang             0x000000010018a4ad main + 1603757
15 clang             0x0000000100047556 main + 280918
16 clang             0x0000000100045b0e main + 274190
17 clang             0x0000000100044cd1 main + 270545
18 clang             0x0000000100019ae2 main + 93922
19 clang             0x0000000100018748 main + 88904
20 clang             0x0000000100006408 main + 14344
21 clang             0x0000000100002e87 main + 647
22 clang             0x0000000100002bf4
Stack dump:
0.  Program arguments: /Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -cc1 -triple thumbv7-apple-ios4.1.0 -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -main-file-name BriefcaseOperationsServiceAgent.m -pic-level 1 -mdisable-fp-elim -relaxed-aliasing -masm-verbose -target-abi apcs-gnu -target-cpu cortex-a8 -mfloat-abi soft -target-feature +soft-float-abi -target-linker-version 134.9 -g -coverage-file /Users/c5180645/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SalesMap-apwauterdbqwwrfeudcmuixcsupw/Build/Intermediates/SalesMap.build/Debug-iphoneos/SalesMap.build/Objects-normal/armv7/BriefcaseOperationsServiceAgent.o -resource-dir /Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/4.1 -dependency-file /Users/c5180645/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SalesMap-apwauterdbqwwrfeudcmuixcsupw/Build/Intermediates/SalesMap.build/Debug-iphoneos/SalesMap.build/Objects-normal/armv7/BriefcaseOperationsServiceAgent.d -MT dependencies -isysroot /Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk -iquote /Users/c5180645/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SalesMap-apwauterdbqwwrfeudcmuixcsupw/Build/Intermediates/SalesMap.build/Debug-iphoneos/SalesMap.build/Sales Maps-generated-files.hmap -iquote /Users/c5180645/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SalesMap-apwauterdbqwwrfeudcmuixcsupw/Build/Intermediates/SalesMap.build/Debug-iphoneos/SalesMap.build/Sales Maps-project-headers.hmap -include-pch /Users/c5180645/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SalesMap-apwauterdbqwwrfeudcmuixcsupw/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/SalesMap-Prefix-etkfpououlszbidzxbhsxwstcvcl/SalesMap-Prefix.pch.pth -D DEBUG=1 -D IBOutlet=__attribute__((iboutlet)) -D IBOutletCollection(ClassName)=__attribute__((iboutletcollection(ClassName))) -D IBAction=void)__attribute__((ibaction) -I /Users/c5180645/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SalesMap-apwauterdbqwwrfeudcmuixcsupw/Build/Intermediates/SalesMap.build/Debug-iphoneos/SalesMap.build/Sales Maps-own-target-headers.hmap -I /Users/c5180645/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SalesMap-apwauterdbqwwrfeudcmuixcsupw/Build/Intermediates/SalesMap.build/Debug-iphoneos/SalesMap.build/Sales Maps-all-target-headers.hmap -I /Users/c5180645/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SalesMap-apwauterdbqwwrfeudcmuixcsupw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/include -I SalesMaps/Libraries -I SalesMaps/Libraries/GSComponent -I SalesMaps/Libraries/VFR -I SalesMaps/Libraries/GSComponent/Classes -I SalesMaps/Libraries/VFR/Classes -I SalesMaps/Libraries/VFR/Resources -I /Users/c5180645/Perforce/SalesMapJan/onDevice/SAPGDBLR_SalesMap_MiOS/dev/src/xcode/../../target/headers/Debug-iphoneos/** -I /Users/c5180645/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SalesMap-apwauterdbqwwrfeudcmuixcsupw/Build/Intermediates/SalesMap.build/Debug-iphoneos/SalesMap.build/DerivedSources/armv7 -I /Users/c5180645/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SalesMap-apwauterdbqwwrfeudcmuixcsupw/Build/Intermediates/SalesMap.build/Debug-iphoneos/SalesMap.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/c5180645/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SalesMap-apwauterdbqwwrfeudcmuixcsupw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -fmodule-cache-path /var/folders/wl/vp1gp4ks6_77xwvbcvlsm8tskgfr5y/T/clang-module-cache -O0 -Wno-trigraphs -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wmissing-prototypes -Wreturn-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wformat -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wno-empty-body -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wno-undeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-sign-conversion -std=gnu99 -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 0 -stack-protector 1 -mstackrealign -fblocks -fobjc-default-synthesize-properties -fobjc-exceptions -fexceptions -fsjlj-exceptions -fpascal-strings -fdiagnostics-show-option -serialize-diagnostic-file /Users/c5180645/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SalesMap-apwauterdbqwwrfeudcmuixcsupw/Build/Intermediates/SalesMap.build/Debug-iphoneos/SalesMap.build/Objects-normal/armv7/BriefcaseOperationsServiceAgent.dia -o /Users/c5180645/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SalesMap-apwauterdbqwwrfeudcmuixcsupw/Build/Intermediates/SalesMap.build/Debug-iphoneos/SalesMap.build/Objects-normal/armv7/BriefcaseOperationsServiceAgent.o -x objective-c /Users/c5180645/Perforce/SalesMapJan/onDevice/SAPGDBLR_SalesMap_MiOS/dev/src/xcode/SalesMaps/Classes/Service Agents/BriefcaseOperationsServiceAgent.m 
1.  <eof> parser at end of file
2.  Code generation
3.  Running pass 'Function Pass Manager' on module '/Users/c5180645/Perforce/SalesMapJan/onDevice/SAPGDBLR_SalesMap_MiOS/dev/src/xcode/SalesMaps/Classes/Service Agents/BriefcaseOperationsServiceAgent.m'.
clang: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
clang: error: clang frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
Apple clang version 4.1 (tags/Apple/clang-421.11.65) (based on LLVM 3.1svn)
Target: arm-apple-darwin12.0.0
Thread model: posix
clang: note: diagnostic msg: PLEASE submit a bug report to http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/ and include the crash backtrace, preprocessed source, and associated run script.
clang: note: diagnostic msg: 
********************

PLEASE ATTACH THE FOLLOWING FILES TO THE BUG REPORT:
Preprocessed source(s) and associated run script(s) are located at:
clang: note: diagnostic msg: /var/folders/wl/vp1gp4ks6_77xwvbcvlsm8tskgfr5y/T/BriefcaseOperationsServiceAgent-bAfEV4.mi
clang: note: diagnostic msg: /var/folders/wl/vp1gp4ks6_77xwvbcvlsm8tskgfr5y/T/BriefcaseOperationsServiceAgent-bAfEV4.sh
clang: note: diagnostic msg: 

********************
Command /Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 254
```

Is there any problem with device or any other thing, some one would have found an answer if you know pls help. 
Thanks

Comment: Are you running on a normal, native file system, e.g. Journaled HFS+ ?

Comment: My xcode version is 4.5

Comment: @Paul: What does a normal native file system mean. Am running a normal Xcode project.

Comment: In other words is your source code on a Windows share, or other server, or on a disk formatted for NTFS, or anything like that ? Or are you just running on a normal Mac hard disk (HFS+) ?

Comment: Am just running on normal mac hard disc. I found this bug also vanishes after removing the project.xcworkspace and xcuserdata.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, its just a link error, just rebuilding the project solves the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar error. In my case cleaning the project and removing the build and derived data did the job.